# Stop jquery fading effect?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to make a blinking light recording effect. Here is the code I have so far:

```js
$("#stop").hide();
function blink() {
  $("#red").fadeOut(500);
  $("#red").fadeIn(500);
}

$("#start").click(function () {
  $("#start").hide();
  $("#stop").show();

  window.test = setInterval(blink, 500);
});

$("#stop").click(function () {
  window.clearInterval(test);
  $("#stop").hide();
  $("#start").show();
});
```

```html
 <button class="success" id="start">Start</button>
 <button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

Here is the blinking light image:

```html
<img src="record.png" id="red" />
```

The image is solid and the jquery fades it in and out.
But when you click the stop button it does not stop; it keeps blinking;
I also tried to use jquery: `.stop();`. But it did not work. How can I fix this? Thanks for all your help in advance!

Comment: Hi Landon, can you clean up your code samples here so they function and we can get a better idea of the problems you're experiencing?

Comment: you've got a few timing issues here that are compounding your problem. You're fading something out over half a second, and then fading it back in over half a second, taking approximately 1 second total. however, you're doing it once every half second, so you end up creating twice as many "blinks" than the allotted time would have allowed to happen. Therefor, your "stop" is in fact working, you just aren't waiting long enough to observe the blinking to stop. If you hit start, wait 5 seconds, then hit stop, you'll have to wait an additional 5-6 seconds for the blinking to end.

Comment: OK, thank you, how can I fix this?

Comment: Fix the math problem.

Comment: I did this: `  $("#red").fadeOut(500);
  $("#red").fadeIn(500);
}`
And then this: `setInterval(blink, 1000);`

Comment: I am sorry, I am still having trouble :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
function blink() {
  $("#red").fadeOut(500);
  $("#red").fadeIn(500);
}

$("#start").click(function () {
  $("#start").hide();
  $("#stop").show();

  window.test = setInterval(blink, 500);
});

$("#stop").click(function () {
  window.clearInterval(test);
  $("#stop").stop();
  $("#start").show();
});
```

It should stop the light after the current interval.

Comment: Yes, that works but:
You did this: `$("#stop").stop();` it should be `$("#red").stop();`
And I found out now that it should be: `window.test = setInterval(blink, 1000);`, not `window.test = setInterval(blink, 500);`